# Java. Вопросы по многопоточности

Tags: java, многопоточность, java-ee, jvm

1. К примеру у меня есть какой-то объект типа Object многопоточное чтение которого происходит гораздо чаще, чем модификация и есть два варианта реализации:

   a)  обычная переменная Object obj и ReadWriteLock соответственно на методы чтения и модификации

   б) volatile Object obj, на метод модификации - простой Lock, создание нового объекта и замены ссылки obj. Метод чтения без синхронизации(не считая записи-чтения volatile переменной)

   Какой из вариантов предпочтительнее и будет работать быстрее и почему?
2. Если я решил делать вариант 1.б и точно знаю, что мое приложение будет запускаться на сервере с несколькими процессорами архитектуры x86-64, то мог ли я вообще убрать volatile и нарушив тем самым JMM, но полагаясь на протоколы когерентности кешей процессоров? прочитает ли ядро 2-го процессора измененные данные в ядре первого и даст ли это хоть какой-то прирост производительности?

Comment: Если у вас изменение это создание нового объекта, а не изменение его самого, то конечно вариант 1.б (или AtomicReference, что почти одно и тоже).

Comment: Ну, вы можете полагаться на сильную memory model x86, но вы должны будете ещё как-то объяснить оптимизатору, что он не имеет права кешировать значение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. 
1. AtomicReference (CAS) тоже самое что и блокировка? выгрузка потока с ядра по идеи более дорогстоящая процедура нежели несколько раз крутанутся в цикле. Хотя конечно большой вопрос сколько это несколько. А разница между созданием и измееннием объекта в консистентности данных насколько я понимаю?

Comment: 2. Так если данные в кешах других ядер-процессоров будут помечены как невалидные когда какой-то поток их изменит и за этим проследит сама железка. Зачем мне как-то обяъснять что-то оптимизатору? Есть у меня к примеру большая мапа у которой на 10000 чтений 1 запись и я максимально хочу не использовать синхронизаицю вообще, чтобы сделать чтение как можно быстрее. Могу ли я в таком случаи намеренно написать неправильный код с точки зрения jmm

Answer (score 4):

Интересный вопрос.  Попробую ответить, хотя не претендую на правильность. Буду рад замечанием в комментариях.

1) Какой вариант будет быстрее? Сказать трудно, потому что все сильно зависит от usecas'а который вы используете. А именно, от количества писателей и читателей, частоты записи и чтения, потребность в "честной" синхронизации или ее критичности и пр.  В общем, нужно замерять и писать тесты. Написал для этого вот такой код :

Для варианта с `Lock`:

```
    private Object object = new Object();
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();             

    Supplier<Object> reader = () -> {
        while (lock.isLocked()) {
        }
        return object;
    };
    Function<Integer, Object> writer = number -> {
        lock.lock();
        object = number;
        lock.unlock();

        return object;
    };
```

Насколько я знаю, `isLocked()` и `unlock()` имеют отношение `happens-before` и надобности в `volatile` для поля `object` нет.

Варианта с `ReentrantReadWriteLock` довольно простой:

```
   private Object object = new Object();
   private final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    Supplier<Object> reader = () -> {
        Object result;
        readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
        result = object;
        readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        return result;
    };
    Function<Integer, Object> writer = number -> {
        readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        object = number;
        readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock();
        return object;
    };
```

Результаты получились следующие, если отношение между читателями и писателями 0.8 то вариант с обычным `lock` оказывается быстрее в 2.5-4 раза ([полный код теста с jmh](https://gist.github.com/izebit/6fe28d0a278409311bad1c07bfa2489e))

2) Из полученных измерений пришел к выводу, что удаление volatile не сыграет существенной роли. Лучше посмотреть в сторону каких-то [альтернативных механизмов синхронизации](http://blog.takipi.com/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized/).

Comment: А в варианте N1 есть ли смысл устанваливать happens-before через isLocked() и unlock()? Насколько я понимаю само запись-чтения volatile переменной его обеспечит. А синхронизая для write нужно чтобы избежать потерянного обновления. возможно я не прав

Comment: похоже на то.  isLock() особо там и не нужен,  если ссылку на объект сделать volatile. Но в примере я пытался добиться такого же поведения что и RW lock -  если идет запись, то чтение запрещается.

Comment: Понятно, большое спасибо за ответ и возможность подискутировать на данную тему)
Интересна разница если как раз не повторять принцип RWLock, а как раз пойти по принципу реализации CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: Производительность CAS'a  будет прямопропорциональна количеству читателей. Заинтересовали, нужно померить =)